# Unfinished text in "Add Comment" box

Tags: bug, comments

I just noticed that the default text in the "Add Comment" box seems to be unfinished:

[image]

I'm guessing this is a mistake, because "Avoid comments like" is pretty useless as a statement on its own ;) I haven't noticed it before, so either it's a new bug or I'm incredibly unobservant. (Or maybe we're advising users to avoid *blank* comments? I suppose that could be it ;)).

Comment: @Bart I glanced through the list of questions it gives you to look at before you post the question, and none of them seemed to be the same. Simple mistake.

Comment: I think the dupes (I'm one of them) are because the original question says "Comment textbox placeholder incomplete". While this is the perfect description it is quite different from "Comment bug in meta" or "Unfinished text in add comment box" so it doesn't show up in the suggestions. PLUS we tend to be in a hurry to ask 
questions and gain rep, sometimes backfiring (as in my case :()